# integer turning to negative in java

Tags: java

why every time I input this value my total elements is turning into negative?
this is what input first 5
then 123, 130, 53, 85, 100

```
import java.io.*;
public class Add{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int element = 1;
        System.out.print("what dimension is your array?: ");
        int dimen = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());
        if(dimen>10){
            System.out.println("your dimension is too large please try again");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int[] Array = new int[dimen];
        for(int a = 0; a<dimen; a++){
            System.out.print("what is the value of your dimension?: ");
            int dimen1 = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());
            Array[a] = dimen1;
            element = element*Array[a];
        }
        System.out.println("The total Value of the element is "+element);
   }
}
```

why is the answer like this?
-1386439592

Comment: Without knowing what `Array` is and what is in it there is no possible way to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you multiply your values of `Array` to `int element = 1;` you are getting

```
123
15990
847470
72034950
7203495000
```

But max value `int` can store is

```
2147483647
```

which is causing [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) to `-1386439592`.

To solve this problem consider changing type of `element` to something which can contain bigger values like

- `long` which can contain numbers up to `9223372036854775807`
- or in case of even bigger numbers `BigInteger`.

Comment: Actually, given the name of his class, I suspect that he should be *adding* the array elements instead of multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to be sure without knowing what `Array` is, but perhaps it's assembled from the last 5 numbers that you entered?

If so, then you're hitting integer overflow. `int` values are limited to about 2 billion before they start wrapping around, and 128 * 130 * 53 * 85 * 100 is over 7 billion.

Use a `long[]` or `Long[]` array instead of `int[]` or `Integer[]`.